# MySQL IF Result Count 0 Return Message

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need the following query to return a message, such as "No Result" if the Record Count = 0.

```
set @ID_CARTERA = 1;

select    

LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) Year,
RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2 ) Quarter,
ROUND ( A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2 ) Quarterly_Yield

from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A

where     A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA
And       (LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) = ( select    MAX(left(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) ) - 0
                                         from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
                                         where     ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA ) 
            and
            RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2 ) = 12)
```

Comment: And what is the expected resultset when there are actually rows that matches the search?

Comment: This is a very odd request.  This seems like you are trying to ask the database to perform application level logic.

Comment: Expected result set is a single record.

Answer (score 0):

you can trick the system like this:

1. generate a query to return COUNT(*). This will always return a row, even if there are zero rows to count
2. Left join your main query with the COUNT(*) query. Use Case statement to replace the results with "No Results".

So, the resulting query will look like (assumption - the main query returns zero or one record only - thus there is no ON clause in the LEFT JOIN!!!!):

```
set @ID_CARTERA = 1;

select    
CASE cnt WHEN 0 THEN "No Results" ELSE Year END,
Quarter,
Quarterly_Yield
FROM
(select count(*) AS cnt
from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A
where     A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA
And       (LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) = ( select    MAX(left(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) ) - 0
                                         from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
                                         where     ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA ) 
            and
            RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2 ) = 12) ) cnt_tbl
LEFT JOIN
( select    
LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) Year,
RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2 ) Quarter,
ROUND ( A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2 ) Quarterly_Yield
from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A
where     A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA
And       (LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) = ( select    MAX(left(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) ) - 0
                                         from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
                                         where     ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA ) 
            and
            RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2 ) = 12) ) main_tbl
```

The same thing can be accomplished with UNION. Ask in the comments if you wish me to show how

Comment: I can see how this will work.  If you would show me now to accomplish the same with UNION that would be great.